# Rebasing a branch that has been branched from

Tags: git, version-control, git-rebase

I'm attempting to cut off a part of the history of a repository so I
can graft it back onto the repository with `git replace` as described
in [this article](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/17/replace.html).

The main difference between the case described in the article and my
repository is, that my master branch has existing branches. I would
like to keep the layout of those branches and their branch-points
equivalent after I have cut away the history.

My history approximately looks like this

```
    cut here
      |
      v
o--o--o--o--o--o--o master
            \  \  \
             \  \  o--o   A
              \  o--o--o  B
               o--o--o    C
```

There are no branches off of master before the "cut here" commit.

What I want to achieve is this:

```
o--o--o history

initial tree at cut
        |
        v
        o--o--o--o--o master
               \  \  \
                \  \  o--o   A
                 \  o--o--o  B
                  o--o--o    C
```

That means it wouldn't be sufficient to just rebase master on the
initial tree but I also need to replay all existing branch on their
equivalent new commit after the rebase of master. I don't want to just
replay all branches on the new master, because that would possibly
have conflicts.

Is there any smart and hopefully automatic way to do this?

Comment: I don't quite see why you need to modify the history. You can apply those commits on top of master without cutting anything away and voilà, your problems with replaying would be solved.

Comment: @MaxLeske You mean the commits in the branches? As said: I'm sure that would lead to conflicts and there are too many branchesto resolve those manually and some of them are quite old .

Comment: Well, I don't really understand why you would want to do anything like that (even the reason given in the article doesn't convince me, you could just just `clone --depth=1`). Nevertheless, couldn't you just use `replace` for this scenario too? Simply replace the "cut here" commit with a dummy commit. Your history will then be lost (for that repository) but you wouldn't have to do any rebasing / replaying.

Comment: @MaxLeske Cloning with a depth would create a not usable repository, as far as I understand the man page. But maybe I'm wrong there. If I do your replace trick, will I be able to replace again with the tip of the history branch?

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you do want to do advanced stuff with a repository and cloned it with a depth too shallow then you won't be able to push (although it will work under different circumstances). As the man page states, replacements are just refs. So yes, you can replace a commit as often as you like and if you choose to delete the replacement you'll end up with your original repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands will have the result you are looking for:

```
git checkout --orphan temp-branch CUT–COMMIT
git commit // This will create your new initial commit
git rev-parse HEAD // To get the SHA of this commit
git replace CUT-COMMIT NEW-COMMIT
git filter-branch -- --all
```

If you have any question regarding to how and why this works, feel tree to leave a comment. You might want to backup your repo before you do stuff like this.

**From the [filter-branch docu](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html)**:

> NOTE: This command honors .git/info/grafts and .git/refs/replace/. If
>   you have any grafts or replacement refs defined, running this command
>   will make them permanent.

Comment: I can follow what is happening up to and including the `git replace`. But I don't understand what filter-branch does here and why it works.

Comment: `filter-branch` rewrites your commit history, so it actually contains what you changed with `replace`. If that makes sense.